# which exception to throw if list is empty in java?

Tags: java

I have the following doubt concerning which exception to throw if list is empty

```
public class XYZ implements Runnable {
    private List<File> contractFileList;

    @Override
    public void run() { 
        contractFileList = some method that will return the list;
        //now i want to check if returned contractFile is empty or not , if yes then raise the exception
        if (contractFileList.isEmpty()) {
            // throw new ?????
        }
    }
}
```

I am runing this code inside a batch, I want  to throw some exception that will stop the batch execution.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That looks like [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) to me.

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time.

Basically your object is not in a valid state for `run` to be called.

I wouldn't create your own exception for this unless you expect it to be deliberately caught elsewhere. It *sounds* like this would only occur due to a programming error rather than an unexpected *situation*... in which case an unchecked exception is appropriate, and `IllegalStateException` describes the general nature of the problem quite clearly.

You can put a detailed cause within the message of the exception (explaining that the "illegal state" was that the list was empty).

I suggest you try to avoid creating a separate exception type for every little thing that can go wrong - unless you're catching these exceptions separately, having different types doesn't help; it only adds to the clutter. An exception which is of the right broad type but has a useful message provides just as much benefit without as much cognitive overhead.

Note that you *can't* use a checked exception if you're implementing `Runnable.run` anyway, as that isn't declared to throw any checked exceptions. You'd have to wrap it in an unchecked exception (e.g. `RuntimeException`) at which point there's even less benefit.

Comment: Thanks Jon ...!! Yes you are right I can't use checked excpetions in Runnable.run(). So I am using IllegalStateException

Comment: 'if(contractFileList.isEmpty()){
throw new IllegalStateExcpetion("contractFileList is empty");

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for this answer. I realised all my custom exceptions were really just fancy `IllegalArgumenException` and `NullPointerException`. Using these broad types with proper messages removed the unsightly Exception classes from my packages.

Answer (score 6):

Make your own exception by subclassing `Exception` and make a descriptive name.

```
public class MyEmptyListException extends Exception {
    public MyEmptyListException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer for why I *wouldn't* do this.

Answer (score 3):

I would keep these points in my mind if I am creating any Custom Exception Class.

- Make sure you have a consistent way of handling exceptions in the whole application.
- Will the new Custom Exception give more information to the developer using your method as to how to recover from the exception?

Please find some links I found useful for understanding Exception Handling..

1. [Best Practices for Exception Handling](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html?page=2)
2. [Does Java need checked Exceptions](http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions)
3. [Unchecked Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Answer (score 3):

I would thrown an `IllegalArgumentException`. As the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) explains it is "thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument".

Answer (score 0):

You should throw `User defined Exception`.

You should create your own exception class and then throw it.

Comment: *Why* do you think the OP should create a new exception for this, out of interest? (My answer explains why I don't think they should.)